# EXCEL adding new columns into nested if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, nested-if

```
=IF(
Payment_Rules = Save_Only,
IF(
    VLOOKUP(
        F7 & $B$13,
        $Y$13:$AC$429,
        IF(
            $Z$11 = $B$6,
            2,
            IF(
                $B$6 = $AA$11,
                3,
                IF(
                    $B$6 = $AB$11,
                    4,
                    5
                )
            )
        ),
        FALSE
    ) < D6,
    D6,
    VLOOKUP(
        F7 & $B$13,
        $Y$13:$AC$429,
        IF(
            $Z$11 = $B$6,
            2,
            IF(
                $B$6 = $AA$11,
                3,
                IF(
                    $B$6 = $AB$11,
                    4,
                    5
                )
            )
        ),
        FALSE
    )
),
VLOOKUP(
    F7 & $B$13,
    $Y$13:$AC$429,
    IF(
        $Z$11 = $B$6,
        2,
        IF(
            $B$6 = $AA$11,
            3,
            IF(
                $B$6 = $AB$11,
                4,
                5
            )
        )
    ),
    FALSE
)
```

)

So far I have nested if statement in my excel file like this and it works fine, but new columns are added to the workbook so I have to tweak this code little bit to cover new columns.(column AC:AF are added)

```
=IF(
Payment_Rules = Save_Only,
IF(
    VLOOKUP(
        F6 & $B$13,
        $Y$13:$AF$429,
        IF(
            $Z$11 = $B$6,
            2,
            IF(
                $B$6 = $AA$11,
                3,
                IF(
                    $B$6 = $AB$11,
                    4,
                    IF(
                        $B$6 = $AC$11,
                        5,
                        IF(
                            $B$6 = $AD$11,
                            6,
                            IF(
                                $B$6 = $AE$11,
                                7,
                                IF(
                                    $B$6 = $AF$11,
                                    8
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        FALSE
    ) < D5,
    D5,
    VLOOKUP(
        F6 & $B$13,
        $Y$13:$AF$429,
        IF(
            $Z$11 = $B$6,
            2,
            IF(
                $B$6 = $AA$11,
                3,
                IF(
                    $B$6 = $AB$11,
                    4,
                    IF(
                        $B$6 = $AC$11,
                        5,
                        IF(
                            $B$6 = $AD$11,
                            6,
                            IF(
                                $B$6 = $AE$11,
                                7,
                                IF(
                                    $B$6 = $AF$11,
                                    8
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        FALSE
    )
),
VLOOKUP(
    F6 & $B$13,
    $Y$13:$AC$429,
    IF(
        $Z$11 = $B$6,
        2,
        IF(
            $B$6 = $AA$11,
            3,
            IF(
                $B$6 = $AB$11,
                4,
                IF(
                    $B$6 = $AC$11,
                    5,
                    IF(
                        $B$6 = $AD$11,
                        6,
                        IF(
                            $B$6 = $AE$11,
                            7,
                            IF(
                                $B$6 = $AF$11,
                                8
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    FALSE
)
```

)

This is what I got for my new code, but it gives me the #REF! error. I can't figure it out what is wrong with. Since original code works fine I know there's nothing wrong with calling reference. How can I fix this error ?

Thank you!

Comment: I think, it would be quite hard to analyze this function without your workbook. Try to use evaluate formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all the IF() inside the VLOOKUP to MATCH:

```
=MATCH($B$6,$Y$11:$DD$11,0)
```

This will not need to be updated unless you have more column than DD.

```
=IF(Payment_Rules=Save_Only,IF(VLOOKUP(F7&$B$13,$Y$13:$DD$429,
MATCH($B$6,$Y$11:$DD$11,0),FALSE)<D6,D6,VLOOKUP(F7&$B$13,$Y$13:$DD$429,
MATCH($B$6,$Y$11:$DD$11,0),FALSE)),VLOOKUP(F7&$B$13,$Y$13:$DD$429,
MATCH($B$6,$Y$11:$DD$11,0),FALSE))
```

Comment: =IF( Payment_Rules = Save_Only, IF( VLOOKUP( F6 & $B$13, $Y$13:$AF$429, MATCH($B$6,$Y$11:$DD$11,0) ), FALSE ) < D5, D5, VLOOKUP( F6 & $B$13, $Y$13:$AF$429, MATCH($B$6,$Y$11:$DD$11,0), FALSE ) , VLOOKUP( F6 & $B$13, $Y$13:$AC$429, MATCH($B$6,$Y$11:$DD$11,0), FALSE ) )

Comment: So I wrote like that but it gives me too many argument for function error. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You also need to change all the `$Y$13:$AF$429` to `$Y$13:$DD$429`